# Help needed using Predicate in Generics

Tags: c#-2.0

Presently i use a method which returns me the ICommand object based on the string comparisons got from the supplied key.

```
public ICommand getCommand(string mCommand)
        {
            foreach (object obj in objCommandList)
            {
                ICommand command = (ICommand)obj;
                if (command.m_strCommandName == mCommand)
                {
                    return command;
                }
            }
        return null;

        }
```

where **objCommandList contains ICommand objects.**

Now I want to improve my code or rather try an alternative to search amongst the collection i.e using an option such as **Predicate** delegate in retrieving the filtered object amongst the collection.

ie.

```
objCommandList.Find(Predicate syntax which is needed here...)
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
objCommandList.Find(delegate(Icommand command) { return command.m_strCommandName == mCommand; });
```

or

```
objCommandList.Find(c => c.m_strCommandName == mCommand);
```